# Android - Use language not available in documentation

Tags: android, multilingual

I am currently developing an app which I want to support both danish and english. I know how things works with resource etc.
My app is currently running Android 2.1 (since most people in Denmark use this), but as far as I know Locale for Denmark is first avaiable in Android 2.3 (documentaion).

What wonders me, is that i got a couple of apps, which support danish language and runs on my phone (2.2). How is that possible?

Do they trick the system in some way, or do they just develop their application in Android 2.3 and make it runnable in lower version devices? Or is it possible to manipulate the native language with another app to make it "default".

I've searched around everywhere, but the danish Android community is very little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible to make a values-da with danish language even though it's not supported in Android 2.2 according to the documentation and it's working fine.
Don't know why it did not work earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

ADB will compile your resources into apk no matter what suffix the folder `values` has (tested on `values-qq`). So I assume you can just add the proper suffix for your language, and these resources will be just ignored on pre-Android-2.3.

Comment: I get an error in Eclipse when I try to make a value-folder named:
values-da_DK, and the project won't compile?
I get: invalid resource directory name values-da_DK /

But if I make a folder named: values-da there is no problem, but my app won't recognize the files, as I get english language in the app.

But it must be possible to trick the system in some way as HandcentSMS and ROM Manager is danish on my phone running 2.2

Comment: `values-en_UK` aint compiled either, so you are useing a wrong suffix probably. But you won't see danish on 2.2 anyway, unless the strings for english locality will be danish. Can you switch your HandcentSMS or ROM Manager from danish to english?

Comment: I got the surfix from here:http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html which I presume must be right?
No I can't switch the language in ROM Manager (Don't have handcent atm), but I'm pretty sure it was not possible there either.


I don't assume both ROM Manager and Handcent was written in danish, so there must be some way to overwrite.
BTW I think the reason you can't compile values-en_UK is because it may be the standard value, so it's just the normal value folder.

Comment: I just did som research on Handcent, and I see that the danish language pack is separately at the moment.
Is it possible that this file maybe overwrite the native language in the app to danish, which will make sense why it's possible. Maybe the original language files are stored on the SD card, and the Languagepack is able to overwrite these files?